# how to submit data to multiple web forms simultaneously-with only captcha and multiple choice values shown on screen

Tags: java, webforms

I want simple java code that enables submission of same/similar data to multiple websites at a time...All the values are initially asked from the user, and just before submission, only multiple choice values (like radio buttons) and captchas are shown on screen. After the user has filled in these values all forms are submitted.

Is it possible to do this in
(a) Regular java application
(b) Google App ENgine Java application

Also some sites require new user to register and then login, only after that multiple form submission has to be done. Can this be implemented in java and how?

Regards,
Arvind.

Comment: Do you know your multiple websites (and their forms) before, or do you want to have this generic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to submit multiple forms.

In the URL below, the author uses Jquery and AJAX with PHP to do it.
Use the same concept using JSP and you should be good.

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/submit-multiple-forms-jquery-ajax.html